# Web.config transformation in smart way

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, configuration

I have client endpoints as below in my web.config, we have production server located geographically for e.g. America, Europe, Asia etc and all have their own base uri.

e.g. web.config is as below

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9000/ServiceA.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IServiceA" name="ServiceA"></endpoint>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9000/ServiceB.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IServiceA" name="ServiceB"></endpoint>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9000/ServiceC.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IServiceA" name="ServiceC"></endpoint>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9000/ServiceD.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IServiceA" name="ServiceD"></endpoint>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9000/ServiceE.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IServiceA" name="ServiceE"></endpoint>
```

For Ameria region I have Web.America.config but it should be transformed as below

```
    <client>
        <endpoint xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(address)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" address="http://localhost:9000/america/ServiceA.svc" name="ServiceA"></endpoint>
        <endpoint xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(address)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" address="http://localhost:9000/america/ServiceB.svc" name="ServiceB"></endpoint>
```

...
...

But I don't want this duplication as I only need to change base address. Is there any better way of doing this?